# Can't access Tomcat externally

Tags: linux, tomcat

I have Tomcat running on my linux box and I can't access my apps externally. I can access it on my box using `localhost:8080` and `[ip-addr]:8080`. It times out if I use `[ip-addr]:8080` on another machine.

I've tried disabling the firewall, but that didn't help.

Any tips?

Comment: Is it listening on only loopback?  If you do a `netstat -pan | grep 8080` or similar with `ss` or something like that, is it bound to an externa IP, or 0.0.0.0 or some form of localhost?

Comment: I don't think so...? I get `tcp6 0 0 :::8080 :::* LISTEN 4064/java`

Comment: Are you trying to connect to it on an IPv6 address?  It looks from that output like it's only listening to IPv6, not IPv4

Comment: Ahh no I'm not. How do I have it listen to IPv4?

Comment: Didn't work, but it's now listening to IPv4 - `tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN`

Comment: Did you try that with the firewall disabled as well?

Comment: Yep...I honestly have no idea what's going on

Comment: Can you run tcpdump on the server and see if you're at least getting the SYN packets and trying to respond?  I trust you have correct routing between the two hosts?  I also assume there is no external firewall between the two hosts

Answer (score 0):

From https://serverfault.com/questions/390840/how-does-one-get-tomcat-to-bind-to-ipv4-address it looks like you want to add `JAVA_OPTS=" $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true "` to your catalina.sh